# Utility to search through VS projects looking for string

Tags: visual-studio, project-management

Can anone recommend a tool for searching my visual studio projects folders to find a specific string value?

I have many solutions / projects stored in either the d:\VS2005 or the d:\VS2008 folder depending on the VS version used to create the project. I'm looking for a string and do not have the foggiest idea which project or solution it is in. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and change Look-in to be `c:\path\to\your\code`.

Edit: Or, from the command line in the root of where you want to search:

```
d:\> findstr /spin /c:"STRING-YOU-ARE-LOOKING-FOR" *.*
```

Or *.cc or *.h or whatever you want to look through.

Comment: findstr is woefully underused.

Comment: upvote for "Spin" :)

Comment: Hey is it the same case for substring also?

Comment: `findstr` basically behaves like grep.  It should find substrings by default.  Easy to test though.

Answer (score 4):

[Entrian Source Search](http://entrian.com/source-search/) is a Visual Studio add-in that does exactly this.  (Full disclosure: I'm the author.)

Comment: It's look like to be a very good tool. I don't find how to filter to display in the result only word that are contains in a string; in quotes but with the preview that you give, it's very easy to find which ones I'm concerned. Thanks!!!

Comment: you should include instructions in your post

Answer (score 3):

I use [WinGrep](http://www.wingrep.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Since "Visual Studio 2010" version Edit.FindinFiles:

Displays the In Files tab of the Find and Replace dialog box.

This is the most handy search as it can search through project, solution and similar combination with reference or without.
Keyboard shortcut is : CTRL+SHIFT+F

More on [MS designers, shares and editors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)